# How I do sub-columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have multiple product that we sold in unit, I want to make an annual table that summarizes monthly sales for each product, by unit, by value and by percent of Sales target

This table ( in the image below ) contains one column for every month, which is sale by unit, how can I add another 2 columns for sales in value and percent versus target for the same month

[Link for the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hozw.png)

Comment: You can't create sub-columns, but you can merge cells in adjacent columns.

Comment: but this will cause a problem in sort, filter and pivot table

Comment: If you've already considered this and other solutions, but they don't work for you for some reason, please add that information to the question using the [edit] button. You don't want to waste yours and our time on repeating solutions that you've already ruled out.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing. I would think you just need to add new columns to the table and rename the existing columns so you have "Sales unit Jan-19", "Sales value Jan-19", "Pct vs. Target Jan-19".

If you want to retain much more flexibility for analysis with pivot tables and charts and so on, you should restructure your data like this:

[image]

With month as a column instead of representing each column, you can have as many measures for that month as you want. These then become easily summative in a pivot table to answer questions such as:

- what was the year-to-date total sales value for all sales people?
- how does that compare to last year?
- what was the sum of units sold for Line 2 in Q1 for the last 5 years?

and so on.